# Checking only continuous NA values in R

Tags: r

I have thousands of data frames like this table as shown below. Each table has 60 rows with number of NA between 1 and 5 in the **value** column. These NA values position is random and can occur in continuous rows or are scattered across 60 rows. I am trying to write a code in R which skips the table like this if only 5 continuous NA's are present at the beginning of the table, anywhere in the middle or at the end. I was thinking of using a *for* loop which picks 60 rows at a time, check for 5 continuous NA's, if present skip to the next 60 rows. I could not think of any other solution than using *for* loop. Any help would be appreciated.

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| filename |   date    | window_no | value |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |    NA |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |    NA |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |    NA |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |    NA |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |    NA |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |    78 |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |    83 |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |    89 |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |    99 |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |    NA |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |    NA |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |   115 |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |   117 |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |   119 |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |   120 |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 |   121 |
| ....     | .......   |      .... |  .... |
| 157E     | 5/28/2017 |         1 | 122.5 |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

I thought of using rle function to find continuous NA's in a table, but can't figure out the algorithm to find the location of continuous NA's. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your `rle` idea is right on. On a sample vector `x`,

```
with(rle(is.na(x)), max(lengths[values]) >= 5)
```

will be TRUE if there are 5 or more `NA`s in a row. Just use `your_data$value` for `x`.

---

To explain, let's get some sample data

```
x = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, NA, 1,1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1)
```

Breaking it down a little, `rle(is.na(x1))` gives the run lengths of both NAs (TRUE, after `is.na`) and non-NAs (FALSE, after `is.na`)

```
rle(is.na(x))
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:5] 8 1 2 5 1
#   values : logi [1:5] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Of course, we only care about the `TRUE`s (the `NA`s), so we subset the `lengths` by the `values`, keeping on the lengths corresponding to TRUE values.

```
with(rle(is.na(x)), lengths[values])
# [1] 1 5
```

Then it's as easy as looking at the `max` of what remains, and seeing if it is above your threshold.

Comment: `a<-rle(is.na(x));inverse.rle(modifyList(a,list(values=a$values&(a$lengths==5))))`

Answer (score 0):

More primitive way: convert NA's into sequence of 1's in a string and use grep to match "11111" which also matches a sequence of 1's longer than 5.:

```
grepl('[1]{5}', paste0(as.character(as.integer(is.na(x$value))),collapse=""))
```